# Write a simple cron job to run a Java class

Tags: java, linux, cron

How can I write a cron job start from scratch to run a java class or write a cron job class with embedded Java code to run?

and how can I set the timer to run every one minute (for example) that cron job?

Note: totally beginner with Linux

Comment: why downvote? I really have no idea to start. that's why ask this question. any help will be really appreciated. If downvote, pls at least give me reasons to help me to improve my question.

Comment: probably because people expect you to at least use google before asking your qeustion here *shrug* well thats what i'd suggest you to do, write your java application in a way that you can use it from the command line, if you got that, google for crontab+example and you will find enough information about how to setup your crontab to run your java application ... beware: in the crontab you ll have to add full pathnames or set the path environment variable first

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample sh file running a test job

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07
echo "Java Home is $JAVA_HOME"
export CLASSPATH=.:..:$CLASSPATH:
echo "Path is is $PATH"
echo "CLASSPATH is is $CLASSPATH"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  TestJob
echo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  TestJob"
```

then point to it from your cronjob like so

```
0 5 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/test/job
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of a simple cron task, you could use [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is also famous for cron jobs in Java.